# pear install on mamp 3.0.

Tags: php, mamp, pear

I am trying to install PEAR on fresh install of MAMP 3.0.  OSX 10.8.5
So far I

1) Changed the directory permissions so I can execute files within them chmod 774 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.9/bin/pear

2) Setup an alias to avoid typing the whole path.
alias mpear="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.9/bin/pear"

3) I checked whether pear is working by:
mpear –V
It all seems OK:
PEAR Version: 1.9.4
PHP Version: 5.5.9
Zend Engine Version: 2.5.0

4) Next I tried to upgrade pear:
mpear channel-update pear.php.net 
and the response I got on Terminal is
channel-add: temp_dir is not writable: "/tmp/pear/install" - You can change this location with "pear config-set temp_dir"
So I am stuck there… Can someone help with config-set – what exactly I need to enter into the Terminal.

Comment: I got so frustrated by this! Never figured out a solution, but it works alright inside of a docker container.

Answer (score 0):

Just use pear's in-built help functionality:

```
$ pear help config-set
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your permissions on the temp folder:

```
cd /tmp/pear
ls -l
```

Mine looked like the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel  136 May  6 14:38 install
```

So it was as simple as running the command under administrator:

```
sudo mpear channel-update pear.php.net
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps!